# How to delete data physically with Presto/Trino?

Tags: hive, presto, trino

In my installation of Presto (358) I've got two working hive connectors:

- S3
- Azure blob (ABFS)

Everything works fine but when I call `DROP (TABLE/SCHEMA)` or `DELETE FROM`, the deletion happens only in metastore and no data is being physically deleted. Applies on both S3 and ABFS.

This becomes quite problematic in case of replacing data:

```sql
> DROP TABLE hive.abc; 
-- ok

> CREATE TABLE hive.abc AS (...) 
-- ERROR: Target directory 'abc' already exists.
```

The same applies on deleting partitions, etc.

Is there any way to *really* delete the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out the solution. The main difference was in specifying **external_location** vs **location** for the schema and its tables.

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA hive.xyz WITH (location = 'abfs://...');
CREATE TABLE hive.xyz.test AS SELECT (...);

DELETE FROM hive.xyz.test WHERE TRUE;

-- Data ARE physically deleted
```

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA hive.xyz;
CREATE TABLE hive.xyz.test 
    WITH (external_location = 'abfs://...') 
    AS SELECT (...);

DELETE FROM hive.xyz.test WHERE TRUE;

-- Data ARE NOT physically deleted.
```

Conclusion: `external_location` for a table will prevent data deletion.